# INSERT INTO Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, key

Can you help me please with adding foreign key from `Addresses` table to `Company` table, thanks.

```
myCommand2.Parametres.AddWithValue(@AddressId", ????????);"

protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName);
    Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
    ...

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    string insertSql1 = "INSERT INTO Addresses(Street, Number, City, Postcode) VALUES (@Street, @Number, @City, @Postcode)";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection1.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(insertSql1, myConnection1);
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", Street);
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number);
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", Postcode);
        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection1.Close();
    }

    string insertSql2 = "INSERT INTO Company (AddressId, UserId, CompanyName, IC, DIC, Web) VALUES (@AddressId, @UserId, @CompanyName, @IC, @DIC, @Web)";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection2.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(insertSql2, myConnection2);
        myCommand2.Parametres.AddWithValue(@AddressId", ????????);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", newUserId);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompanyName);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC", Ic);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIC", Dic);
        myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Web", Web);
        myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection2.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: I think we need to know the schema of `Company` in order to answer this question.

Comment: Schema: Table1: Company (CompanyId int, UserId uniqueidentifier, AddressId int, CompanyName nvarchar, IC nvarchar, DIC nvarchar, Web nvarchar). Table2: Addresses (AddressId int, Street nchar, Number nchar, City nchar, Postcode nchar). Relationship FK_Company_Addresses, Primary Key table Addresses-AddressId, Foreign key tabble Company-AddressId.

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AddressId', table 'C:\USERS\PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\WEBSITES\AS2015\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF.dbo.Company'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: According to your last comment, you have an error when trying to insert a record into Adresses table. Have you configurated your table to auto generate the IDs?

Comment: Yes, I have auto generate the IDs in table Adresses. The error is during insert value into table Company. Problem is during insert foreign key AddressId from table Adresses to table Company.

Comment: SOLVED: I use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()